# How to Add Y axis and Legend to a tree diagram?

Tags: tikz-trees, legend, axis

I am trying to add 2 things to my diagram below:

1. Legend to just say that W: Wastage, S: Sold in a box
2. Add Y axis as time, with curly braces to specify periods

Any suggestions/links to how I can go about it

TIA

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \hfill\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,circle},
   level distance=1.75cm,sibling distance=1.2cm, 
   edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
\Tree [.\node {Q}; 
        \edge node[auto=right] {Period 1};
    [.$Q_1$  
        [.$W$ ] [.$S$ ]
    ]
    [.$Q_i$
        \edge node[auto=right] {Period i};
      [.$Q_2$ 
            \edge node[auto=right] {Period 2};
         [.$W$ ] [.$S$ ]
      ] 
      [.$W$ ]
    ] 
       ]
\end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{\texttt{Inventory Carryover }}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Could you make your code into a compilable example, please?

Answer (score 2):

This uses Forest, which I'm familiar with. No doubt you can adapt it for whatever packages you're using to get your code working. (Presumably `tikz-qtree` is somewhere in your preamble, even though you've tagged it `tikz-trees` which suggests Ti*k*Z's own library.)

However, Forest is rather more powerful and flexible, which no doubt makes things a bit easier.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,array}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    circle,
    draw,
    math content,
    l sep*=2,
    s sep*=3,
    minimum size=2.5em,
    fit=band,
    tier/.option=level,
  },
  period/.style={
    edge label={node [midway, left, anchor=south east] {Period $#1$}},
  },
  before drawing tree={
    tempcounta/.max={>O{level}}{tree},
    tikz+={
      \coordinate (w) at ([xshift=-10pt]current bounding box.west);
      \foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,...,\foresteregister{tempcounta}} \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (!{group={r,until={>On={level}{\i}}{next node}}} -| w) -- (!{group={r,until={>On={level}{\j}}{next node}}} -| w) node [midway, left, xshift=-5pt] {Time Interval \i} ;
    },
  },
  [Q
    [Q_1, period=1
      [W]
      [S]
    ]
    [Q_i
      [Q_2, period=i
        [W, period=2]
        [S]
      ]
      [W]
    ]
  ]
  \node [anchor=north west] at (current bounding box.north east) {%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}@{}>{:}c@{\hskip 5pt}l@{}}
      \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{Legend}\\
      S && Sold in a box\\
      W && Wastage\\
    \end{tabular}};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: temporal tree]

Comment: Thank You. While running the code, I get the following message: "! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/forest/tier/.option', to which you passed 'level', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it." I checked your solution to a similar problem but am not able to apply it here. Kindly help.

Comment: @Insoucyant You need to update your TeX distribution. You have a very outdated version of Forest - probably version 1, if I'm not mistaken. If you absolutely cannot update, you can use something like `tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1}{level}` instead, but updating would be far preferable.